# extending jquery static typedef in typescript

Tags: jquery, typescript

So basically I want to extend the `JQueryStatic` interface to accommodate my jquery extensions.

Can someone guide me on how to make it work? Here's what I have

```
interface JquerySocialExtension { 
    (selector: JQuery.Selector): {social: (options?) => any };
};
export interface JQueryStaticExtended extends JQueryStatic, JquerySocialExtension { };

let $1 : JquerySocialExtension
let $2: JQueryStaticExtended;

$1('div.mine').social(); //no compile error
$2('div.mine').social(); //gives compile error
```

Now I'd assume that since I extend `JQueryStaticExtended` with both  `JQueryStatic` and `JquerySocialExtension`, it should merge both the implementations but unfortunately it fails.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that extension order matters. This should be fine:

```js
interface JQueryStaticExtended extends JquerySocialExtension, JQueryStatic {}
```